# django_session table is not found after making migrations?

Tags: python, django, session, migration

I changed model and deleted migrations, **pycache** folders as well sqlitedb file of the application in the project.

Then I tried 
`python manage.py makemigrations appname 
python manage.py migrate appname`

Answer (score 0):

Just migrate without the app name.

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname
python manage.py migrate
```